# How to count the number of cells in a row that have a number greater than 7 as part of the text such as "8 days"

Tags: excel, excel-formula, office365

I have a spreadsheet that has several columns. I'm only going to show data from 2 of them here, because they're the 2 that I'm dealing with in this problem.

The first column is IP Addresses. The second column is how long ago the last response was or the last response date:

| Address | Last Response |
| --- | --- |
| 10.1.1.109 | 10/17/2022 |
| 10.1.1.113 | 10/17/2022 |
| 10.1.1.137 | 10/17/2022 |
| 10.1.1.188 | 4 days |
| 10.1.1.199 | 10/17/2022 |
| 10.1.21.5 | 10/17/2022 |
| 10.1.21.50 | 45 days |
| 10.1.50.41 | 10/17/2022 |
| 10.1.50.71 | 10/17/2022 |
| 10.1.88.10 | 10/17/2022 |
| 10.1.88.249 | 6 days |
| 10.16.6.190 | 4 days |
| 10.64.0.76 | 28 days |
| 10.64.3.48 | 45 days |

What I need to do is to get a few counts worked out. I want to know how many from each IP subnet have

1. A response older than 1 week
2. A Response older then 1 month.

In the sample data you can see 3 IP subnets: 10.4, 10.16, and 10.64. I am expecting to get results like:

| IP Subnet | > Week | > Month |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 10.1 | 9 | 1 |
| 10.16 | 0 | 0 |
| 10.64 | 2 | 1 |

I have a formula for the "> Week", but I don't like it. I am not able to figure out how to count based on the number at the beginning of the text in that column. I tried a formula like this:

```
=COUNTIFS(AllIPAddresses,"10.1.*",AllResponses, NUMBERVALUE(LEFT(AllResponses, FIND(" ",AllResponses)))&">7")
```

Obviously this doesn't work. It gives me a column full of 0's.

What I have working for the "> Week" column:

```
=COUNTIFS(AllIPAddresses,CONCAT(A2,"*"),AllResponses,"<>7 days",AllResponses,"<>6 days",AllResponses,"<>5 days",AllResponses,"<>4 days",AllResponses,"<>3 days",AllResponses,"<>2 days",AllResponses,"<>Today",AllResponses,"<>Yesterday")
```

But like I said, I don't like it as it is just looking at the column and not counting 8 of the options. I would prefer if I could have a way to get it to look at the column and count those whose number of days is > 7. Something simple would be great, but something that is shorter and/or simpler than what I have I'll take. And I cannot reuse that effectively for the "> month" result because then I'd have to list some 30 different options that I don't want to count.
It would be better to have it look for the 1 option that I do want.

I'm hoping for something like:

- First COUNTIFS counts all the text that have a number > 7
- Second COUNTIFS counts all the dates that are more than 7 days before today

```
=COUNTIFS(AllIPAddresses, CONCAT(A2,"*"),AllResponses, LEFT(AllResponse,2)&">7")+COUNTIFS(AllIPAddresses, CONCAT(A2,"*"),AllResponses,"<"&today()-7)
```

And then I can reuse this for the "> month" by changing the 7 to a 30.

Though I know this formula doesn't work.

Any assistance with this problem would be appreciated!

**Some Notes about my formulas**
For ease of use I have named ranges:
**AllIPAddresses** = A2:A700
**AllResponses**   = B2:B700
*(in my formula for > week)* **A2** is referring to the "10.1." so that the `CONCAT` will give the result of "10.1.*" to the `COUNTIFS`

**EDIT**

I have added an answer that explains why I chose the solution that I did and how I had to tweak the answers I received to make them work for my specific scenario.

Comment: So the function now() will give the exact date and time - it is also volatile so gets recalculated on opening, saving etc. From the date & time you can subtract 7 days etc as needed.

Comment: @SolarMike thanks for the help, but that doesn't solve the problem I'm having. Using Today() gives me the date, that's all I really need, and works fine against the cells that are dates. I'm having a problem with the cells that contain a number and then text.

Comment: Wouldn't `10.1` > Week be `9` instead of `8`?

Comment: @P.b you are correct. I miss counted in the question. I changed some of the numbers when I put them in here so I could show a decent sample. Thanks for the catch.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This could be accomplished using:

```
=LET(data,A2:B15,
     _d1,INDEX(data,,1),
     _d2,INDEX(data,,2),
         lr,TODAY()-IF(ISNUMBER(_d2),_d2,TODAY()-(LEFT(_d2,LEN(_d2)-LEN(" days")))),
         lft,TEXTBEFORE(_d1,".",2),
         unq,UNIQUE(lft),
         sq,SEQUENCE(COUNTA(lft),,1,0),
         mm,--(TRANSPOSE(unq)=lft),
            wk,MMULT(--(TRANSPOSE(lft)=unq)*TRANSPOSE(lr>7),sq),
            mn,MMULT(--(TRANSPOSE(lft)=unq)*TRANSPOSE(lr>30),sq),
               stack,HSTACK(unq,wk,mn),
VSTACK({"IP Subnet","> Week","> Month"},stack))
```

[image]

`lft` uses `TEXTBEFORE` to get the first 2 sections of the IP address.
`lr` calculates the number of days of the last response compared to today.
`unq` is the unique values of `lft` (IP subnet).
`wk` uses `MMULT` to calculate the conditional count of unique IP subnet values where `lr` is greater than 7.
`mn` is the same as `wk`, but where `lr` is greater than 30.

Comment: This took a little tweaking to get it to work for me, but it is working. I've never used the "Let" formula in Excel before, it is very useful!

Comment: Yeah, it allows you to create a dictionary, get better readability and it doesn't need to recalculate these values every time it's referenced in the formula. So useful and powerful.

Comment: Yes @P.b is one person I must say who uses `LET()` function very smoothly & elegantly I have seen here. Nice solutions.

Answer (score 1):

**Perhaps** you could ***try***:

[image]

---

• Formula used in cell `D2`

```
=LET(_ipaddress,TEXTBEFORE(Address,".",2),
_days,IFERROR(TODAY()-ISNUMBER(Last_Response)*Last_Response,
           SUBSTITUTE(Last_Response," days","")+0),
_uip,UNIQUE(_ipaddress),
_week,BYROW(_uip,LAMBDA(x,SUM(--(x=_ipaddress)*(_days>7)))),
_month,BYROW(_uip,LAMBDA(x,SUM(--(x=_ipaddress)*(_days>30)))),
VSTACK({"IP Subnet","> Week","> Month"},HSTACK(_uip,_week,_month)))
```

---

### Explanations of each named variables used to make the calculations:

• **Address** --> is a defined name range and refers to

```
=$A$2:$A$15
```

---

• **Last_Response** --> is a defined name range and refers to

```
=$B$2:$B$15
```

---

• **_ipaddress** --> extracts the **IP Subnet** using `TEXTBEFORE()`

```
TEXTBEFORE(Address,".",2)
```

[image]

---

• **_days** checks whether the range is a number or text, since in Excel dates are stored as a number, we are using `ISNUMBER()` to check which returns `TRUE` and `FALSE` for text values,

So that said, the **first part** of the `IFERROR()` checks and returns the number of days,

```
TODAY()-ISNUMBER(Last_Response)*Last_Response
```

[image]

---

While the **second part** which is a text value, we are only substituting the " days" with empty and converting it to a number as well.

```
SUBSTITUTE(Last_Response," days","")+0
```

[image]

---

```
=IFERROR(TODAY()-ISNUMBER(Last_Response)*Last_Response,
           SUBSTITUTE(Last_Response," days","")+0)
```

---

[image]

---

• **_uip** --> This gives us the Unique **IP SUBNET**

```
UNIQUE(_ipaddress)
```

---

• **_week** --> this gives us the count for each unique values row wise and returns as an array of output, for those days which are greater than 7 days.

```
BYROW(_uip,LAMBDA(x,SUM(--(x=_ipaddress)*(_days>7))))
```

[image]

---

• **_month** --> while this gives us the count for each unique values row wise and returns as an array of output, for those days which are greater than 30 days.

```
BYROW(_uip,LAMBDA(x,SUM(--(x=_ipaddress)*(_days>30))))
```

[image]

---

• Last but not least, we are packing all the variables that are needed to show as an output with in an `HSTACK()`

```
HSTACK(_uip,_week,_month)
```

[image]

To make it look good with a proper header we are wrapping it within an `VSTACK()`, along with the headers, [1x3] array

[image]

---

[image]

---

### Well, you can also perform such tasks quite easily using **Power Query** as well:

To accomplish this task using **Power Query** please follow the steps,

[image]

---

• Select some cell in your Data Table,

• **Data Tab** => **Get&Transform** => **From Table/Range**,

• When the PQ Editor opens: **Home** => **Advanced Editor**,

• Make note of all the **2 Tables Names**,

• Paste the **M Code** below in place of what you see.

• And refer the notes

---

```
let
    //IPAddresstbl Uploaded in PQ Editor,
    Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="IPAddresstbl"]}[Content],

    //Date Type Changed
    #"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source,{{"Last Response", type text}}),
    
    //Extracting the IP SUBNET 
    #"Extracted Text Before Delimiter" = Table.TransformColumns(#"Changed Type", {{"Address", each Text.BeforeDelimiter(_, ".", 1), type text}}),

    //Replacing " days" in last response column
    #"Replaced Value" = Table.ReplaceValue(#"Extracted Text Before Delimiter"," days","",Replacer.ReplaceText,{"Last Response"}),
    
    //Removing " 12:00:00 AM" from Date Time since we changed the data type of lastresponse as text
    #"Extracted Text Before Delimiter1" = Table.TransformColumns(#"Replaced Value", {{"Last Response", each Text.BeforeDelimiter(_, " 12:00:00 AM"), type text}}),

    //Adding custom column return the numbers of days
    #"Added Custom" = Table.AddColumn(#"Extracted Text Before Delimiter1", "Custom", each if Value.Is(Value.FromText([Last Response]), type number) then [Last Response] else Date.From(DateTime.LocalNow()) - Value.FromText([Last Response])),
    
    //Changing the data type of the custom column to ensure they are numbers
    #"Changed Type1" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(#"Added Custom",{{"Custom", Int64.Type}}),
    
    //Removing unwanted columns
    #"Removed Columns" = Table.RemoveColumns(#"Changed Type1",{"Last Response"}),
    
    //Returning 1 for those days which are more than 7 else returning as 0    
    #"Added Conditional Column" = Table.AddColumn(#"Removed Columns", "> Week", each if [Custom] > 7 then 1 else 0),

    //Returning 1 for those days which are more than 30 else returning as 0
    #"Added Conditional Column1" = Table.AddColumn(#"Added Conditional Column", "> Month", each if [Custom] > 30 then 1 else 0),
    
    //Grouping by each IP Address
    #"Grouped Rows" = Table.Group(#"Added Conditional Column1", {"Address"}, {{"> Week", each List.Sum([#"> Week"]), type nullable number}, {"> Month", each List.Sum([#"> Month"]), type nullable number}}),

    //Renamed the IP Address Column
    #"Renamed Columns" = Table.RenameColumns(#"Grouped Rows",{{"Address", "IP SUBNET"}})
in
    #"Renamed Columns"
```

---

[image]

---

[image]

---

• Change the Table name as **SUBNETtbl** before importing it back into Excel.

• When importing, you can either select **Existing Sheet** with the cell reference you want to place the table or you can simply click on **NewSheet**

---

Comment: I have never used Power Query before, I was able to get it working for me after some tweaking to your code. I didn't choose this answer as the solution only because I was able to get the "Let" formula from P.B.'s answer to work first. Using Power Query might end up being what I use in the future though as I have more transformations to do now that I have this one working.

Comment: Hey @Mike never mind, getting acceptance or vote is not the main concern for me, but to provide best flexible dynamic and scalable solutions, I have followed lot of experts here to learn and develop skills, though my `Power Query` may be that not perfect, but it works, Hope some experts look at the solution and guide me for more better solution.  Glad I was able to help and thanks for your kind words. It really sounds nice

Comment: Yes, it really helped me a lot. And I'll continue to work with Power Query in the future especially on this particular file that I reference in this question.

Answer (score 1):

**Answer chosen information**
I choose the answer by [P.b](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74280308/how-to-count-the-number-of-cells-in-a-row-that-have-a-number-greater-than-7-as-p/74281980?r=Saves_AllUserSaves#74281980) because I was able to get it to work for me first. I did have to tweak the code he provided like this:

```
=LET(data,AllData, _d1,INDEX(data,,1)
, _d2, INDEX(data,,4)
, lr, TODAY()-IF(ISNUMBER(_d2),_d2,TODAY()-(IF(_d2="Today","0",IF(_d2="Yesterday","1",LEFT(_d2,LEN(_d2)-LEN(" days"))))))
, lft, TEXTBEFORE(_d1,".",2)
, unq, UNIQUE(lft)
, sq, SEQUENCE(COUNTA(lft),,1,0)
, mm, --(TRANSPOSE(unq)=lft)
, wk, MMULT(--(TRANSPOSE(lft)=unq)*TRANSPOSE(lr>7),sq)
, mn, MMULT(--(TRANSPOSE(lft)=unq)*TRANSPOSE(lr>30),sq)
, stack, HSTACK(unq, wk, mn)
, VSTACK({"IP Subnet", "> Week", "> Month"}, stack))
```

This is what I was able to get working for me. It gives me the list of IP Subnets and the counts of how many of the IPs' *"Last Response"* was longer than 7 days or 30 days.

---

I have also used the Power Query example provided by [Mayukh Bhattacharya](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74280308/how-to-count-the-number-of-cells-in-a-row-that-have-a-number-greater-than-7-as-p/74284835?r=Saves_AllUserSaves#74284835). I was able to get this working as well. I did not test out the *"let"* formula that he provided as I already have a *"let"* formula working. I didn't chose that answer as the solution only because I was able to get the other *"let"* formula working first. I did have to tweak this answer as well in Power Query to look like this:

```
let
    //AllData Uploaded in PQ Editor,
    Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="AllData"]}[Content],

    //Date Type Changed
    #"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source,{{"Last Response", type text}}),
    
    //Extracting the IP SUBNET 
    #"Extracted Text Before Delimiter" = Table.TransformColumns(#"Changed Type", {{"Address", each Text.BeforeDelimiter(_, ".", 1), type text}}),

    //Replacing " days" in last response column
    #"Replaced Value 1" = Table.ReplaceValue(#"Extracted Text Before Delimiter"," days","",Replacer.ReplaceText,{"Last Response"}),

    //Replacing the "Today" and "Yesterday" with numbers
    #"Replaced Value 2" = Table.ReplaceValue(#"Replaced Value 1", "Yesterday", "1", Replacer.ReplaceText, {"Last Response"}),
    #"Replaced Value 3" = Table.ReplaceValue(#"Replaced Value 2", "Today", "0", Replacer.ReplaceText, {"Last Response"}),
    
    //Removing " 12:00:00 AM" from Date Time since we changed the data type of lastresponse as text
    #"Extracted Text Before Delimiter1" = Table.TransformColumns(#"Replaced Value 3", {{"Last Response", each Text.BeforeDelimiter(_, " 12:00:00 AM"), type text}}),

    //Adding custom column return the numbers of days
    #"Added Custom" = Table.AddColumn(#"Extracted Text Before Delimiter1", "Custom", each if Value.Is(Value.FromText([Last Response]), type number) then [Last Response] else Date.From(DateTime.LocalNow()) - Value.FromText([Last Response])),
    
    //Changing the data type of the custom column to ensure they are numbers
    #"Changed Type1" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(#"Added Custom",{{"Custom", Int64.Type}}),
    
    //Removing unwanted columns
    #"Removed Columns" = Table.RemoveColumns(#"Changed Type1",{"Last Response"}),
    
    //Returning 1 for those days which are more than 7 else returning as 0    
    #"Added Conditional Column" = Table.AddColumn(#"Removed Columns", "> Week", each if [Custom] > 7 then 1 else 0),

    //Returning 1 for those days which are more than 30 else returning as 0
    #"Added Conditional Column1" = Table.AddColumn(#"Added Conditional Column", "> Month", each if [Custom] > 30 then 1 else 0),
    
    //Grouping by each IP Address
    #"Grouped Rows" = Table.Group(#"Added Conditional Column1", {"Address"}, {{"> Week", each List.Sum([#"> Week"]), type nullable number}, {"> Month", each List.Sum([#"> Month"]), type nullable number}}),

    //Renamed the IP Address Column
    #"Renamed Columns" = Table.RenameColumns(#"Grouped Rows",{{"Address", "IP Subnet"}})
in
    #"Renamed Columns"
```

---

Now that I have started using Power Query I will probably continue with it as I have more transformations on this data to work on.

Answer (score 0):

Using new 365 functions, generate unique IPs value, and count for >7 and >30 days.
If date retrieve differences, otherwise extract days number:

```
=LET(IP,TEXTBEFORE(AllIPAddresses,".",2),U,UNIQUE(IP),S,SEQUENCE(COUNTA(AllIPAddresses),,1,0),D,IFERROR(TODAY()-AllResponses,TEXTBEFORE(AllResponses," ")*1),W,MMULT((TRANSPOSE(IP)=U)*(TRANSPOSE(D)>7),S),M,MMULT((TRANSPOSE(IP)=U)*(TRANSPOSE(D)>30),S),HSTACK(U,W,M))
```

with `HSTACK` combine columns results.